# Print Class Variables in Swift - Expected Declaration Error

Tags: swift, subclass

do you know what's wrong?
I just want to print a class' variable.
I think the print have to be inside a method, but I don't know how exactly.

```
import UIKit


class Class {
    var name: String
    init(name:String){
        self.name
}

class Subclass : Class {
    var level: Int
    init(name:String, level:Int){
        self.level
        super.init(name: name)
    }
}

var subclass1 = Subclass(name: "Hallo", level: 10)
print(subclass1.level)            // <-- here I get the error "Expected Declaration"
```

[Screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ij3iC.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not very familiar with Swift, but it looks like you are missing the declaration in your init.

```
...
self.name = name
...
```

And

```
...
self.level = level
...
```

Hope it helps.

You are also missing a curly brace in the code.

```
class Class {
    ...
    init(...) {
    ...
->}//missing
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks a lot for your quick response!

The missing declaration in my init was a careless mistake by creating the minimal working example. The problem's solution was the missing bracket.

Sorry for my flippancy :(